# How to set width and height of a polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I can't set the width and height of a polygon

How to do that in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Willy's excellent suggestion of the "Improved Polygon Capturing" plugin, depending on your circumstances, is the "Rectangles, Ovals Digitizing" tool.

There is yet another plugin to consider (there's always more than one way to skin a cat in GIS!).  This is the similarly named "Rectangles, Ovals, Diamonds" tool.  This tool is actually a buffering tool rather than a digitizing one.  If you have a lot of polygons to produce where you already know the centroids of each polygon, then this tool can prove very effective.   You create a point data set and add width, height and rotation fields.  The tool then creates a polygon data set by buffering the points according to the values in your three new attribute columns.  However, the buffers this tool creates are not circular but square or elliptical (diamonds being obviously merely rotated squares).

Answer (score 1):

install the plugin
"Improved Polygon Capturing"

Comment: Thank you :) and how to make an exact square from this plugin?

Comment: Once you start using this tool, you will see it can have the length and angle locked to create specific dimensions.  So if you lock 1 m and 90 deg, it should go around in a square. You can use negative values. (Is this like an orthogonal traverse?) Note the deg field can be toggled for canvas or relative angles.   Also, all this works better for me if the layer is in a grid/UTM coordinate system and if the canvas is in grid/UTM system.

Comment: Use the tab key to move between the fields, toggle the locks off and on with the spacebar on the keyboard. That way you can leave the mouse on the canvas. Shift-tab reverses the movement of the selector on the fields.